# Storing a generic class and calling an overridden method in its non-generic derived class

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

Yeah. Talk about confusing titles. So this is the scenario: I've a generic class `PromiseListener` which looks like this:

```
public class PromiseListener<T>
{
    public virtual void IsResovled(T value)
    {
        return;
    }

    public virtual void IsSpoiled()
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to be implemented and its methods overridden. An implementation of this class may look like this:

```
public class TestPromiseListener : PromiseListener<float>
{
    public override void IsResovled(float value)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RMI RETURNED VALUE " + value);
    }
}
```

This `TestPromiseListener` is what's implemented by users. What I need to do is store listeners in a dictionary (key is irrelevant for this problem). This is the context of the problem: a `promise` is an unresolved return-value of a remote method which may eventually resolve to an actual value. A promise is immediately returned when a remote method invocation is made. So then you can "install" a `PromiseListener` whose methods have been implemented by a derived class (`TestPromiseListener`). One of these methods is `IsResovled` which takes one argument: the return value of the remote method invocation. This method would be called when the remote method invocation finally returns a value.

I'm having trouble storing the objects in a dictionary. I could store the listeners as `object`, but I don't see how I could get a listener from the dictionary without knowing the type first, because I would need to know its original type to cast it to. When fetching the PromiseListener I only know the type of the return value (and all information to fetch the right listener from a dictionary). So what I'm asking is: is there a type-safe way to store these generic objects, fetch them and call their methods?

(Some more detailed info as requested - sorry for the wall of text)
Both `IsResolved` and `IsSpoiled` may be called at different times. A promise can resolve if a return value has been received (calls `IsResolved`) or it may be spoiled when no return value could be received (due to a network error, for example) (calls `IsSpoiled`). The `PromiseListener` a user implements may choose to override any of these methods. So internally I have a method which is called when a return value has been received from the network. In this method I have the identifier for the listener (key in the mentioned dictionary), the actual return value (object) and the AssemblyQualifiedName of the return value (which I can use to convert the return value of type `object` to the correct type). I'll then have to find the correct listener - which I can because I have its identifier - but I don't know how to fetch it in a type-save way because I don't know what type the listener is supposed to be.

```
?Type? listener; // Don't know what type the listener is. Could be PromiseListener<string> or PromiseListener<int> - or anything, really
if(promiseManager.TryGetPromiseListener(promise, out listener)
...
```

Comment: You want to call which method? `IsResovled` or `IsSpoiled`? can you pls add a pseudocode of what you're trying to achieve ?

Comment: I guess you're out of luck. You cant get generic all the way in a same collection. Even if you manage to get it you can't call `IsResovled` because it takes `T` as parameter, in order to do that you may need to lose some type safety if you need to store everything in a single collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there some reason why you can't use a **non**-generic base class?

```
public abstract class PromiseListenerBase
{
    public abstract Type PromisedType { get; }
    public abstract void HandleResolution(object value);
}

public class PromiseListener<T> : PromiseListenerBase
{
    public override Type PromisedType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }
    public override void HandleResolution(object value)
    {
        T val = (T)value;
        this.IsResolved(val);
    }

    public virtual void IsResolved(T value) { /* some logic */ }
    public virtual void IsSpoiled() { /* some logic */ }
}

public class FloatListener : PromiseListener<float>
{
    public override void IsResolved(float value)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("FloatListener value {0}", value);
    }
}

public class IntListener : PromiseListener<int>
{
    public override void IsResolved(int value)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("IntListener value {0}", value);
    }
}

public class SomethingUsingPromiseListeners
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<string, PromiseListenerBase> listeners =
            new Dictionary<string, PromiseListenerBase>();
        listeners.Add("float", new FloatListener());
        listeners.Add("int", new IntListener());
        int someValue = 123;
        foreach (PromiseListenerBase listener in listeners.Values)
        {
            if (listener.PromisedType == someValue.GetType())
            {
                listener.HandleResolution(someValue);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to fetch a `PromiseListenerBase` from the dictionary, I wouldn't be able to call the `IsResolved` method in its derived class without casting it to a `FloatListener` or an `IntListener` first. Or I would have to put a virtual method in the base class - which I can't because it needs the generic type parameter from the derived class. (implying I haven't got the picture completely wrong in my head)

Comment: I've edited my answer to show one way to handle what I think you're looking for. See if that helps.

Comment: It bloody works. This is a brilliant solution, and does exactly what I'm looking for! It doesn't work for floats yet, because somewhere during the entire thing (my thing, not your thing) the 'float' is converted to a System.Double, while a float is actually a System.Single - so the typecasting fails (can't cast Double to Single). Silly thing.